# Reacted popup works differently on iOS than desktop

Tags: reactjs

I have doc in my app that slides out from the side so it’s maybe 100px wide. I have some buttons here to open modal dialogs using reactjs-popup. On the desktop this dialog is centered in the veiwport and works how I want it to work.

However on iOS phone or iPad the popup is within the smaller child div and only the edge is visible.

```
<Popup trigger={<button className="gtCpButton"> Remove Player </button>} modal>
    {close => (
      <div className="modal">
        <div className="content">
            <p>As Table Owner you can remove players, they can rejoin if the table is still public</p> 

            <div className="gtKickmeRow">
              <span>Select a player remove</span>     
              <select id="gtKickme">
              {this.state.seatingData.map((seat)=>{
                if (seat.playerid !== this.props.PlayerId)
                  return(<option key={seat.playerid} value={seat.playerid}>{seat.displayname}</option>)
                return null;
                }) 
              }
            </select>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div className="ConfirmButtons">
          <button onClick={() => {this.removePlayer(); close();}} >Kick Player </button>
          <button onClick={() => {close();}} > Cancel </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )}
  </Popup>
```

[image]

Here is how it looks on the desktop

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it, this was not an issue with popup.

The issue was the bounding div had the css set like this

overflow: auto;

Apparently on Ios this defaulted to clipping and on the desktop auto meant visible.  Changing this to

overflow: visible;

solved the problem.